Segmentation fault with multidimensional arrays whose size is determined at runtime
I created a program that is supposed to read two 3D matrices from a binary file, multiply them, and print the result to a binary file. However, while it successfully compiles, when I run it, it gives me a segmentation fault error.
Here is the code I used for the program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    int n2;

    int matrix1[n][n][n], matrix2[n][n][n], result_matrix[n][n][n];

    FILE *file1, *file2, *result;

    file1 = fopen("matrix1.bin", "rb");
    file2 = fopen("matrix2.bin", "rb");

    fread(&n, sizeof(int), 1, file1);
    fread(&n2, sizeof(int), 1, file2);

    if (n != n2 || n > 100) {
        printf("Error: Incompatible matrices or n greater than 100.");
        return 1;
    }

    fread(matrix1, sizeof(int), n * n * n, file1);
    fread(matrix2, sizeof(int), n * n * n, file2);

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                result_matrix[i][j][k] = 0;

                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                    result_matrix[i][j][k] += matrix1[i][j][l] * matrix2[l][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    result = fopen("result.bin", "wb");

    fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, result);
        
    fwrite(result_matrix, sizeof(int), n * n * n, result);

    fclose(result);

    return 0;
}

This is specifically where the segmentation fault is happening:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555c3a in main () at 31504085_1.c:35
35                    result_matrix[i][j][k] += matrix1[i][j][l] * matrix2[l][j][k];

What can you do to help fix this issue?

Your n is uninitialized when you declare the array. You can't declare a VLA like that and read the dimensions later. This is undefined behavior. Also, depending on the implementation, using a VLA with a large n may blow up the stack even if you fix the first issue and move the array declaration after the read. You should use malloc.

If you're not getting warnings, crank up your compiler's settings until it whines about uninitialized variables.

@JonathanLeffler Consider reopening, or editing the dupe to account for multidimensional array case, or finding a better dupe target.

Multidimensional arrays are a logical extension of the 1D array case.  I'll add a comment that it applies to multi-dimensional arrays, but it really is superfluous.

@JonathanLeffler The difference is largely that you can make use of the variably-modified type feature and keep the syntax for accessing multidimensional arrays instead of being forced to use a one-dimensional array and do the manual index calculation. If you still think this is a minor point then I'll let the community decide.

As the comments pointed out, you should really turn up your level of warnings in your compiler flags. This is what you can get if you do so. The warning messages clearly points out the issue,
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:8:5: warning: 'n' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    8 |     int matrix1[n][n][n], matrix2[n][n][n], result_matrix[n][n][n];
      |     ^~~
<source>:5:9: note: 'n' declared here
    5 |     int n;
      |         ^

Using an uninitialized variable produces an indeterminate value, which is not undefined behavior per se, but using an indeterminate value to declare an array (specifically, a VLA, more on that topic later) can lead to undefined behavior because the precondition that the size expression must evaluate to to a value greater than zero may be violated. When it does lead to undefined behavior, anything can happen, and a segfault is one of the many possible outcomes. Undefined behavior or not, using an indeterminate value to declare the array is semantically wrong and definitely what you want to achieve.
So the first attempt to fix would be:
    int n;

    /* ... */

    fread(&n, sizeof(int), 1, file1);
    
    /* ... */

    int matrix1[n][n][n], matrix2[n][n][n], result_matrix[n][n][n];

When you declare an array like matrix1[n][n][n], where the extents for the dimensions are not integer constant expressions, you are using a feature in the C language that is called the variable-length arrays(VLAs for short). This feature is not required to be supported by a standard-conforming C compiler and by definition your program is not very portable. With that in mind and assume that you know for sure that your compiler does support VLAs, and since C23, this also implies the support for variably-modified types (VMs), let's further examine other issues of your code.
Assuming that your implementation does use a stack, it is up to the implmentation whether to put the VLA on the stack. On typical implementations, the stack size is limited, and if you try to use a VLA that takes up too much space the stack would blow up and result in a segfault again. Since we have already assumed that your implementation supports VMs, you should instead use a malloc to allocate the memory for the VLA in the free store. By taking advantage of the support for VM, you can do so without losing the convenience of the multidimensional array access syntax. To make things easier, we can use a typedef. I have also modified the code to check for the return value of fread to guard against an empty file. You should also always check the return value of other standard library functions in your program if they are available.
    int n;

    /* ... */

    if(fread(&n, sizeof(int), 1, file1) != 1){
        fputs("Failed to read matrix dimension.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    /* ... */
    typedef int (*matrix_t)[n][n][n]; //A variably-modified type
    matrix_t matrix1 = malloc(sizeof *matrix1);
    if(!matrix1){
         fputs("Malloc failed: matrix1.\n", stderr);
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    matrix_t matrix2 = malloc(sizeof *matrix2);
    /* ... */

Then, inside the loops, you can dereference the pointer to perform the actual computation,
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                (*result_matrix)[i][j][k] = 0;

                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                    (*result_matrix)[i][j][k] += (*matrix1)[i][j][l] * (*matrix2)[l][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

At the end of the function, you should remember to free the allocated memories,
    free(matrix1);
    free(matrix2);
    free(result_matrix);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


Using n uninitialized produces an indeterminate value, not undefined behavior. And undefined behavior does not mean anything can happen; it means the C standard does not restrict what can happen. Those are different things.

@EricPostpischil Using an indeterminate value as an index in the VLA should be UB, right? I agree the wording can be improved.

No, it would not be undefined behavior. It would be as if the index had some value, but the C standard does not specify what that value is.

@EricPostpischil "Each time the flow of control passes over the declaration, expression is evaluated (and it must always evaluate to a value greater than zero)". Seems the precondition is violated, so it should be UB. The quote is from cppreference, I haven't checked the standard.

The precondition may or may not be violated; it depends on what value is used for n. So the situation can lead to undefined behavior, but it is not undefined behavior per se. It is only undefined behavior when the C standard is entirely hands off about what happens. But it is not; rules about indeterminate values apply and govern program behavior until something triggers undefined behavior.

These differences may be tricky for a novice, but they affect debugging and other work with programs.

@EricPostpischil Adjusted the wording. You may directly edit the answer if you still find it not satisfying.

@EricPostpischil: One could argue the following: Because at least one of the permissible unspecified behaviors invokes undefined behavior, the C standard does not impose any requirements on the behavior of the entire program.
